# Handling a variable number of arguments at runtime in a struct

Tags: c++, c, arrays, struct

I have to classes, an Executer with these methods:

1. Executer()
2. struct Execute(string s)
3. Lookup(string name, int module, int num, ...)

and a Parser:

1. Parser()
2. struct Parse(string s)

The Exectuers Execute method calls the Parsers Parse method. The Parser then chucks the string into smaller bits (it explodes the string on the ;-sign) and returns a struct to the Execute method. This struct it uses to call the Lookup method. 
The struct that the Parse returns holds some standard information:

1. An command name
2. A senderId (a username, a mac address and a password)
3. **A variable number of arguments**

And that is my problem. The Lookup method take variable arguments, but how do I handle the the hand over of these variable arguments by the struct? Im not an expert in C and C++. Should I mass the two classes togheter? So the Parser method could call the Execute method, sparing the struct away.
Or maybe there is a way of parsing an unknown variable of arguments at runtime? By some sort of array?

**EDIT**
I cant use the STL library from C++. I only use the C++ class and virtual feature. Im writing to an compiler where Im restricted to use almost all of the C libraries + the magic skills of C++ (virtual and class). SOory for not telling that right away.

**EDIT 2**
Im writing code to an embedded system and thereby using avr-gcc to compile my code. Thats why I cant use STL. The avr-gcc doesnt support this.

Comment: How do you intend to use this variable set of arguments?

Comment: The variable set of arguments is passed to a Commands Execute method. This method is pure virtual, and holds code that a programmer has defined. The Command is found by the Lookup method (it goes through a list and finds the command that matches the module id and the command name that is passed to Lookup method). It is then up to the programmer that implements the Commands Execute method to handle the arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use std::vector<> or a simular container that can hold an arbitrary number of entries.

```
struct {
  std::string commandName;
  sender_t senderId;
  std::vector<arg_t> arguments;
};
```

Edit: oh, you can't use std::vector. In that case: use an array and store the length:

```
struct {
  const char* commandName;
  sender_t senderId;
  int argumentCount;
  int maxArgumentCount; // you might not need this
  arg_t* arguments; // pointer to array of (at least) argumentCount elements.
};
```

Use malloc() or new() to create the array for the `arguments`.

I would suggest to wrap the argumentCount, maxArgumentCount and arguments in a separate class, which can handle the malloc/new and free/delete as well. This will make it easier to prevent memory leaks.

In the end, you'll have written your own vector_of_arg_t class, so maybe have a look at some basic vector implementation. There must be tutorials on that on the web.

Comment: Oh. Im sorry :( I have tagged the wrong way. I use the virtual and class C++ features. I have forgotten to write that I cant use the C++ STL library. This is because of compiler restrictions. I have updated my question.

Comment: @mslot Huh? "They" don't want you to use well-tested, optimized code but prefer you to reinvent the wheel? Strange...

Comment: Embedded system. Im using the avr-gcc compiler so I cant use the neat C++ features other than class and virtual.

Comment: @mslot oh well, sometimes you don't get what you want. I've updated my answer to reflect that situation.

Comment: Sjoerd you gave me some code and thats way I have checked your answer.

Comment: Note after "revelation" this is for embedded system: dynamic allocation might be a bad idea, prefer memory pools or static buffer.

Answer (score 1):

You could declare your Lookup method as follows:

```
void Lookup(string name, int module, int num, std::vector<std::string> &args);
```

By storing the variable arguments in an `args` array, you can have as many as you want.

Comment: As I have edited, I cant use the STL library. I have updated my question. But maybe I could do this with a standard C like array?

Comment: Yes, you certainly could. Assuming you're allowed to call `malloc()`, that is.

Comment: Aaah Im allowed to do that!! In my Parse method I call malloc, return the pointer in the struct and parse the pointer, or what the array contains, to the Lookup function.

Comment: I have given you +1 for telling me the right way in the comment. I havent checked it because Sjoerd have given me some code to chew on.

Answer (score 1):

See

Q: How can I write a function which takes a variable number of arguments and passes them to some other function (which takes a variable number of arguments)?

A: In general, you cannot. Ideally, you should provide a version of that other function which accepts a va_list pointer.

Suppose you want to write a faterror function which will print a fatal error message, then exit. You might like to write it in terms of the error function of question 15.5:

```
    void faterror(const char *fmt, ...)
    {
        error(fmt, what goes here? );
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

but it's not obvious how to hand faterror's arguments off to error.

```
<snip>
```

Read on at

http://c-faq.com/varargs/handoff.html

Comment: +1 for the link!! I have googled this alot before asking here, and I didnt found this. Thanks.

Comment: It's quite obscure. I only remembered it cause I was forced into a position like the OP a long time ago. It's messy to write vararg C functions and even messier to do handoff.